# Import Data to Excel Using SQL/OLE DB

Tags: sql, excel

I'm trying to recreate an excel file that I had found that imported data into a table using an OLE DB Query Connection that made use of a SQL server. When I go to the connection properties of the connection I'm trying to recreate, there's no connection file and the connection type states that it is an OLE DB Query. It has a lengthy connection string with the information of the SQL server and then the SQL command text that tells the query basically what to search for.

I am using the 2010 v. of Excel so I go to Data > From Other Sources > Data Connection Wizard > Other/Advanced....

I have no idea where to go from there. I've tried clicking on the OLE DB for SQL but it doesn't seem like it's right as it'll delete itself because there's apparently too much data from the query and it'll take too long to load.

Comment: So your using a linked server to connect to an excel file and are you asking for another alternative way to get the excel file to SQL Server?

Comment: not necessarily an alternative way unless that's better in someway. Essentially the OLE DB connection is pulling information from SQL and throwing it into an excel table